# Powershell. Как корректно получить кириллицу в ответе Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: powershell

При запросе к API через Invoke-RestMethod получаю ответ с кракозябрами вместо кириллицы..
Как корректно получить кириллицу в ответе Invoke-RestMethod?

charset в headers не помог...

Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0):

Кодировку подставите какую вам нужно:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/' -UseBasicParsing
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($response.RawContentStream, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
$str = $reader.ReadToEnd()
```